# When and where are the standard in, out, and error file descriptors first opened in linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, stdout, file-descriptors, stdin, stderr

Where are stdin, stdout, and stderr (the fds) **first** opened? Is it the kernel that does it? And when and where are the symlinks /dev/std{in,out,err} made? Where is the code that does it?

I assume it is in the linux kernel source code but I wasn't able to find where it happens even after a search in the archlinux 6.5.3-arch1-1 linux kernel github repo.

edit: please, if you are downvoting this question can you explain why so I can make it better? I would really like to know about this question. It is not easy to find the answer.

Comment: Can someone explain the reason for downvoting the question? I asked originally on stackoverflow and a commenter said I should ask over here.

Comment: You're mixing a number of different things; stdin/stdout/stderr are file descriptors 0/1/2 for a process. by convention.  `/dev/std{in,out,err}` are file system constructs that are unrelated to process, but they're symlinks into `/proc/self/fd/{0,1,2}`.  The `/proc/.../fd` entries reflect the open file descriptors for a process.   What is it you're asking?  Is it where the symlinks get created?  Where the `/proc` entries get created?  Where the file descriptors get opened?  I didn't downvote the question, but it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure you expected what looks like a simple question to be so complicated :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris Quite the contrary, I've been looking into this for the past 24 hours and expected a complicated answer. Ideally, an answer would contain the info for each question you provided. I would really like to know where and when the symlinks /dev/std* are first created, where/when/how the /proc/self/fd/{0,1,2} fds are first opened. Is it the kernel that does all this? How/where(what files) ?

Comment: What is the process that opens them? Is it the shell? Before one logs in via tty, what is process that is running -- is it still the init process that displays that login prompt? Would that be the process that first opens 0,1,2 for further child processes to inherit, e.g. the shell ? p.s. thank you for the response -- love your personal site/blog btw bookmarked it.

Comment: I'd start by looking at `fork` and `exec` - then go down the rabbit hole from there

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm already in the rabbit hole. I can't find where/what is the first thing in my archlinux system that opens fds 0,1,2. I want to go to that piece of code (whether its in the linux kernel source code or in say the bash source) and add another "special"  "systemwide" fd and set it up in the same way stderr is setup. e.g. on my  system there will be not just be stdin, stdout, stderr but these plus one more.. say (customerr) that all scripts and programs can use to read/write to the terminal

Comment: If you're looking for the first thing that opens them, well, then I suppose one would need to ask _which_ fds 0,1,2 you mean? It might be that `init` (the first process to run in userspace) opens those for itself, but possibly only to `/dev/null`. Then, when you start something on a terminal line, e.g. getty or a login program, it's going to need fds connected to that terminal, and is likely to put them as fds 0,1,2. A graphical terminal emulator will likely set up some pseudo-terminal, and open file descriptors to that...

Comment: "Arch Linux Github repo" (I'm assuming [archlinux/svntogit-packages](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages) and the like) won't contain the source code itself, instead it contains [PKGBUILD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PKGBUILD)s, patches and associated files necessary to build packages.

Comment: @Vilinkameni I meant the archlinux's 6.5.3 linux repo. It contains the kernel  source code. https://github.com/archlinux/linux/tree/3669558bdf354cd352be955ef2764cde6a9bf5ec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a process is started, part of the work the operating system performs is to create the data structure that manages the process's file descriptors, and in a common case, populate descriptors 0, 1, and 2 with the pointers to its controlling terminal device.  Some processes are launched with those file descriptors linked a different device than a terminal (often the /dev/null device).  Some processes have one or more of these file descriptors linked to an interface that leads to another process (usually a pipeline), or to a file (i.e., "redirection").  While the parent process may make the function calls to open files/pipes for these descriptors before spawning the child process, it's still the kernel that manages the data structure that tracks the file descriptors.  If you need to know this kind of detail, a book on Unix/Linux internals can tell you.

Each process has its own individual list of file descriptors, so there isn't some universal set of descriptors or device files that you can point to and say they were created at one particular date/time.  The descriptors for a process were created when that process was launched, and new processes are launched a lot, so file descriptors are being created all the time.  (and destroyed when a process exits and the operating system cleans up after it)

You ask about /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout, and /dev/stderr.  These are virtual devices (often called "logical" devices) rather than physical devices.  If you look at them with a command like `ls -l /dev/stdin` you'll see it's a symbolic link to another file like `/proc/self/fd/0`.  Look at `/proc/self` and you'll see it's a symbolic link to a directory that's a number - in fact, the numeric process id of the `ls` program you asked the shell to invoke.  If you open a different terminal and list its `/proc/self` , you'll see it points to a different process id, the one for the `ls` invoked by the second terminal's shell.  The `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout`, and `/dev/stderr` links were created at one particular time, but they point into a set of directories where the directories and files are actually an view into the kernel's data structures around managing processes.  These data structures have different values for different processes (such as the process id), and new parts are created and deleted as processes are launched and terminated.

I didn't downvote your question, but my guess is that this seemingly simple question actually requires a lot of knowledge of the internals to answer accurately.  And it's not something that will be obvious in the kernel source code.  That's why I mentioned getting a book on internals to help you dig into it.  This kind of Q&A forum has limitations, and extended tutorial-style answers about the OS internals don't fit well here.

Comment: Thank you for the great, detailed answer! I'll have to look for some recent books on linux internals. are there any that would likely go into details like this that you know of? I would like to have a modified system that has 4 fds per process stdin, stdout, stderr, custom_err. Not for any good reason. I just want to learn how it is initially set up. I'll mark as accepted but really I wanted to know exactly where is the code that initially provides these three fds for reading/writing to the terminal. if there are three, then there could be four.

Comment: Julie P. answered here  and indicated it is actually the shell that opens the std{in,out,err} fds if the shell is a tty.

Comment: "part of the work the operating system performs is to open the process's file descriptors 0, 1, and 2" -- but is it? Does Linux do that? The [POSIX text](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) seems to only say that it _may_ be done, and the [Linux man page for `execve()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) only appears to qoute that, not saying what Linux actually does

Comment: @ilkkachu I've re-worded my answer to make it clear I'm talking about the creation/management of the data structures for file descriptors instead of which process opens a file.  The OP's mention of dredging through the kernel source made me believe that was more on point than who invokes the `open()` and `dup2()` calls.

Comment: @SottoVoce, yes, the answer (now) says "part of the work the operating system performs is to ... and populate descriptors 0, 1, and 2 with the pointers to its controlling terminal device" and my question is, _is it_? And phrased like it is here, it is not, since the fds might already point to something completely different instead of any terminal. But even if the three fds are not open already, it's not clear at all that it's the job of the OS (any OS) to open them, or that Linux in particular would do it.

Comment: In fact, Linux _doesn't_ do it, E.g. you can run `cat 1<&-` or `cat >&-` and it'll give you an error ("Bad file descriptor") instead of reading or writing from/to the terminal.

Comment: When a process is `fork()`d then it inherits a copy of the file descriptors from the parent, so stdin/out/err point to the same place as the parent process.  They do not necessarily point to the control terminal.  It's then up to the child to decide what to do next (eg close them if it wants to become a daemon).   The only special case is the very first process (init/systemd/whatever) where I _think_ the descriptors are set as closed (so an attempt to use them will generate error 9 EBADF) and the `init` process itself has to open them (eg to `/dev/console` or whever).

Comment: @SottoVoce Do you know who calls open() and dup2() (or there logical equivalent) to open fds on 0,1,2 for the first time? I'd like to understand when is the first time on a linux system that stdin, stdout, stderr are opened for a process, and when/what creates the symlinks /dev/std* and the /proc/self/fd/0,1,2 entries. I now know thanks in part to the comments and responses here and some browsing of the archlinux latest kernel source that the /proc/self/ are created by the kernel when processes are launched. So that last part is covered but it would be great to know the rest.

Comment: @ElfenDew, who opens them first? Likely `init` or whatever the first userspace process is. Just those particular fds might have nothing to do with the fds your shell eventually gets when it runs. There are no "the" fds 0,1,2 that would be rhe same system-wide.

Comment: @StephenHarris "it inherits a copy of the file descriptors from the parent", yes but this copy isn't performed by magic.  I'm describing the kernel as the thing that performs the copy.  Are you saying something else does this copy?  Yes, you point out that the parent's and child's descriptors may not point to a terminal, but I already said that in my answer.

Comment: @ilkkachu see my comment to StephenHarris just a moment ago.  The child process's file descriptors are copied from it's parent process.  I'm saying the kernel ("the operating system") performs that copy of the file descriptor data structure.

Comment: I mentioned "copy" to distinguish from your "and populate descriptors 0, 1, and 2 with the pointers to its controlling terminal device. ".  The kernel doesn't treat 0/1/2 in any way special; they're just file descriptors to be copied.

Comment: @SottoVoce, I don't think anyone is questioning that the kernel needs to do bookkeeping on open fds for the child. What I'm commenting on is the part where you say _"and populate descriptors 0, 1, and 2 with the pointers to its controlling terminal device"_. That's the part I'm questioning here. Are you sure those fds are in any way special during a fork or exec? I don't understand why you keep trying to dodge the question.

Comment: @ilkkachu I did not say there's anything special about file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 compared to other file descriptors.  I don't know where this interpretation comes from.  My answer focuses on those three descriptors because **they are the topic of the OP's question** (clearly visible in the question's Title and the first sentence of the Body).  I haven't been dodging this question, it's the first time you've expressed it clearly.

Comment: @SottoVoce, those are the only three fds your answer explicitly mentions. Why would it do that if they weren't special? Are you working on the assumption that those fds are connected to terminal, and hence the OS needs to set up pointers to account for that? If so, then why not say _that_ instead of unqualified claim that the OS's job is to connect those _particular_ fds to the terminal? Like I just showed you, it's quite possible to start a program with one of the fds 0,1,2 closed. Connected to nothing, no data structures needed.

Answer (score 1):

No, the kernel does not care. They are opened in early startup userspace code, before entering main()